# How to change the BaseUrl on a Hudson behind a Proxy?

Tags: java, apache, proxy, continuous-integration, hudson

How can i change the BaseUrl on a Hudson behind a Proxy?

I'm running a Hudson installation behind a proxy.
The problem is, that any url (email, jabber, tray app) in the web application is set to the local proxy and not to the virtual host. How can i fix that, is there any environment variable?

I have just found "Hudson Url" for email's, but thats all.

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ProxyPass       / http://127.0.0.1:8070/
    ProxyPassReverse    / http://127.0.0.1:8070/
    ProxyRequests       Off

    <Proxy http://127.0.0.1:8070/*>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jabber is an extension and the tray app is a separate application, only email is built-in, and you found the setting for that one. I don't think there is any way to have them use the same setting.

You can change the url used by the tray app if you right-click or double click the tray icon (see http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Hudson+Tray+Application for the exact instructions)

Looking at the Jabber plugin page it looks like the item 'proxy support' is on their list of 'Planned in future releases' so you probably will have to wait or fix that one yourself.

And a side note:
I'm assuming you left something out of your virtualhost setting? Otherwise, what is it meant to do? You can change the port that Hudson is listening on using the --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT switch (see http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Installation+and+Execution)

Comment: Yes, it's not the complete virtual host configuration. I use this approach to handle LDAP/Exchange authorization and IP range restrictions, because the build in module doesn't work very well. The other problem is, i don't want to show anything to guest users.

I can start the tray app with the link, but it try's to download from localhost.